# transport is NoneType when using UNIXClientEndpoint of Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to implement a simple client with twisted using datagram and named pipe.

I define the protocol as follow:

```
class ConsoleProtocol(protocol.DatagramProtocol):

    def __init__(self, machine, console_path):
        self.console_path = console_path
        self.transport = None

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        self.logger.debug("datagramReceived()")
        # blah, doing stuff !

    def sendHalt(self):
        self.logger.debug("sending message to fifo %s", self.console_path)
        self.transport.write("ahaha", self.console_path)
```

And connect it to the UNIX client endpoint:

```
console_endpoint = endpoints.UNIXClientEndpoint(reactor, console_path)
console_protocol = ConsoleProtocol()
endpoints.connectProtocol(self.console_endpoint, self.console_protocol)
```

But during execution of the method `sendHalt()`, the transport argument is `NoneType`. What is the correct way to use an UNIX client with Twisted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoints aren't for datagram protocols.  You need to use `reactor.listenUNIXDatagram(console_path, console_protocol)`.  Be sure not to confuse UNIX sockets and named pipes: they are different, incompatible things.  Twisted doesn't include support for communicating over named pipes.

Comment: `listenUDP` wait for a port number, but this is not the case: i used named pipe so I've only a path to the FIFO.

Comment: Oops sorry.  UNIXClientEndpoint is *not* for named pipes, it's for AF_UNIX sockets.  However, I've updated my answer to be correct for datagrams over unix sockets.

Comment: Your solution is right but I've still a litle problem: `listenUNIXDatagram()` want to create the socket file. Is there a way to use `listenUNIXDatagram()` to an existing socket file ?

Comment: @Jean-Paul Calderone according to [this link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.twisted/17088) you can use Twisted with named pipes. Is it still valid?

Comment: Twisted itself still doesn't ship with built-in support for named pipes.  It is possible to build this yourself (or perhaps find someone else's 3rd party implementation.  You just have to implement `IFileDscriptor` for a named pipe.